# What causing this Android RuntimeException

Tags: android

What causing this Android RuntimeException?

```
02-01 15:13:41.316: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cccc.xxxx/com.cccc.xxxx.ActivityMyScreen}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentView required: pkg=com.cccc.xxxx id=3145728 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0)
```

I am starting this activity from other activity as follows:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setClass(mContext, ActivityMyScreen.class);
 intent.putExtra("username", mUserName);
 startActivity(intent);
```

What might be cause of this Exception?

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all in the error message... the arguments/parameters you use for "contentView" are wrong... just read the error message!

And the code of your onCreate in MyScreenActivity is more important to find the issue than the intent you create.